# PHP file_get_contents Usage

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm attempting to use 'file_get_contents' to get the details of the current song which is playing from a given URL (http://s4.voscast.com:7080/currentsong) and pass the value to a variable.

This doesn't work, no data is passed to the $songinfo variable:

```
$songinfo = file_get_contents('http://s4.voscast.com:7080/currentsong');
echo "Now Playing: " . $songinfo;
```

However the following shortened versions of the URL both work, and return data into the variable, so I don't understand why the above example isn't working?

```
$songinfo = file_get_contents('http://s4.voscast.com:7080');
echo "Now Playing: " . $songinfo;
```

```
$songinfo = file_get_contents('http://s4.voscast.com');
echo "Now Playing: " . $songinfo;
```